# Найти между несколькими скобками значения JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, match

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь вытащить значения, которые лежат в строке между скобками. Пока продвинулся не далеко. Вот что имею:

```
'{1}{2}{3}{4}'.match(/\{(.*)\}/)[1]; // 1}{2}{3}{4
```

Не могу понять почему выводится, `1}{2}{3}{4`, когда я написал, чтоб выводилось всё, что находится между фигурными. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что спецсимвол `.` (точка) равнозначен любому символу, включая скобки, и выборка происходит как раз согласно вашему выражению: все символы от самой первой открывающей скобки, до последней закрывающей.

Вы можете модифицировать ваше регулярное выражение, чтобы выбрать *"первое значение, заключенное в скобки"* (не обязательно число), указав вместо `.` исключение закрывающей скобки `[^\}]`:

```
'{1}{2}{3}{4}'.match(/\{([^\}]*)\}/)[1] // 1
```

Однако, если вам нужно получить массив всех чисел из строки строго данного формата, куда проще сделать следующим образом:

```
'{1}{2}{3}{4}'.match(/\d+/g); // ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

- [Регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 9):

"Жадный" квантификатор действительно находит как можно больше текста, Other отлично всё объяснил, однако само `(.*?)` не поможет, ведь нужно получить в результате все числа в фигурных скобках. `String#match` не поможет, так как при использовании глобального модификатора, `match` просто опускает все захваченные подмаской подсовпадения.

Нужен `RegExp#exec`, а выражение для чисел в фигурных скобках - `{(\d+)}`:

```js
var s = '{1}{2}{3}{4}';
var re = /{(\d+)}/g;
var res = [];
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Если вы работаете в среде JS, которая поддреживает стандарт ECMAScript 2018, проблема решается ещё проще с помощью блоков предварительного просмотра вперёд и назад:

```js
var s = '{1}{2}{3}{4}';
var re = /(?<={)\d+(?=})/g;
console.log(s.match(re));
```

Answer (score 8):

Хм, всё верно.
Вероятно, Вы имеете ввиду что ожидалось что-то типа: `1`, `2`, `3` и `4`.
Тут виновата [жадность](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy) квантификаторов.
Жадные пытаются взять как можно большую подстроку для проверки, и **уменьшают** её ради совпадения.
Ленивые наоборот - ищут минимум и **увеличивают** подстроку при необходимости.

---

У Вас 1 и последний символ подходят, вот жадный и взял его.

Превращение в ленивый квантификатор даст то, что нужно (тогда нужно добавить модификатор глобального поиска `g`, иначе найдя `1`, `match` успокоится):

```js
console.info('{1}{2}{3}{4}'.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g));
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
console.info('{1}{2}{3}{4}'.match(/[^{}]+(?=})/g));
```

Увы, в javascript нет [просмотра назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) в регулярках.

**UPD** Другой вариант. **Нюанс**: вернет массив с 1 пустым элементом, а не null, если совпадений не будет найдено:

```js
console.info('Привет}}}}'.match(/{[^{}]+(?=})|$/g).join('').slice(1).split('{'));

console.info('{}{Привет'.match(/{[^{}]+(?=})|$/g).join('').slice(1).split('{'));

console.info('{}{Привет}{Мир}{{}{'.match(/{[^{}]+(?=})|$/g).join('').slice(1).split('{'));
```

Comment: *Увы, в javascript нет просмотра назад в регулярках.* - поэтому надо объяснить, что выражение `/[^{}]+(?=})/` найдет совпадение `111111` в `"111111}}}"`